# Pass command line args to Java app (Spring Boot) running in Docker

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, dockerfile, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to pass command line args to the main method of a **Spring Boot** app running in a **Docker container**. Running from the command line, I would do something like this:

```
 $ mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.arguments=--greeting=Hello,--recipient=World
```

The app needs to pick these args up and do some processing with them:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Options options = new Options();

    Option greeting = new Option("-g", "greeting", true, "Greeting");
    greeting.setRequired(true);
    greeting.addOption(greeting);

    Option recipient = new Option("-r", "recipient", true, "Recipient");
    recipient.setRequired(true); 
    recipient.addOption(recipient);

    try {
        cmd = parser.parse(options, args);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        formatter.printHelp("utility-name", options);
        System.exit(1);
    }

    // Do some processing using these args ...

    // Run the Spring Boot app
    SpringApplication.run(SpringBootApp.class, args);
}
```

I have tried simply passing them in using the `-e` flag:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -d -e "greeting=Hello" -e "recipient=World" test-image
```

My `Dockerfile` looks like this:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
VOLUME /tmp
COPY ./target/spring-boot-app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

Since options (args) are required, I keep receiving an error message and the app exits.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can provide all command line arguments just after name of your docker image in `run` command.

**Example:**

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 test-image --recipient="World"--greeting="Hello"
```

Comment: Awesome. I haven't seen anything resembling starting the container this way while trying to figure this out. Thanks @Evgeniy Strepetov

Comment: Please note: passing system arguments only works if you have _exec_ form entrypoint (e.g.: `["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app.jar"]`). Details are described [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint)

Answer (score 12):

You can try to modify your `ENTRYPOINT` in your `Dockerfile` like that:

```
ENTRYPOINT exec java -jar -Dspring-boot.run.arguments=--greeting=Hello,--recipient=World
```

Or you can pass argument at run:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 test-image --recipient="World"--greeting="Hello"
```

Comment: I tried something similar with ENTRYPOINT but the syntax was a little funky, but this makes total sense. Thanks @veben

Comment: Setting fixed values for the arguments in the `ENTRYPOINT` line in the Dockerfile does not make sense to me.